# CEF for C#/Mono on OS X Crashes on javascript:window.close()

Tags: c#, macos, mono, chromium-embedded

We are building a project that is using the Xilium/CefGlue Mono library, in order to render our user-interface in a Chromium embedded frame. Pages load and display in an NSWindow. JavaScript is executed on the page and on page events.

However, the application crashes with a FATAL message when calling

```
window.close();
```

anywhere in the page's JavaScript. Last bit of output prior to the crash is

```
FATAL:message_pump_mac.mm(765) Check Failed: [NSApp conformsToProtocol:@protocol(CrAppProtocol)]
```

Is this related? Is there some way we can have NSApp conform to this protocol in C#/Mono?

For more information, here is a similar topic posted in the [CEF forum](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=14814&sid=8b6587c5e3c0d7c87ca1d5ff23be66d9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this comment in include/cef_application_mac.h:

```
// All CEF client applications must subclass NSApplication and implement this
// protocol.
@protocol CefAppProtocol<CrAppControlProtocol>
@end
```

https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src/master/include/cef_application_mac.h?at=master#cef_application_mac.h-80

Comment: Is there some way to conform to this protocol in C#/Mono?

Comment: @DanielLawhead Example implementation is in cefclient_mac.mm/cefsimple_mac.mm files: https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src/dce5d5c28f2743740e68a59e8cfa9605c672aef8/tests/cefsimple/cefsimple_mac.mm?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#cefsimple_mac.mm-19